How to use chartjs plugins in laravel filament V3 widgets?
I am trying to use the chartjs plugin chartjs-plugin-datalabels in my doughnut chart widget. I have done the steps mentioned in the this filament documentation
I am using as in the below code for the widget. I am able to see the chart but I am not seeing the data labels. I am not sure how to use the plugin in side my code.
class PaymentStatusChart extends ChartWidget
{
    protected static ?string $heading = 'Payment Status';

    protected function getData(): array
    {
        $studentFees = StudentFee::groupBy('status')
        ->selectRaw('status, count(*) as count')
        ->get();

        return [
         'datasets' => [
            [
                'label' => 'Payment Status',
                'data' => $studentFees->pluck('count'),
               'datalabels' => [
                   'anchor'=> 'center',
                   'backgroundColor' => null,
                   'borderWidth'=> 0
               ],
                'backgroundColor' => [
                    'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                    'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
                ],
                'borderColor' => '#9BD0F5',
            ],
        ],
        'labels' => $studentFees->pluck('status'),
      ];
    }

    protected function getOptions(): array
    {
      return [
        'plugins' => [
            'legend'     => ['display' => true,],
            'datalabels' => [
                'display' => true,
                'borderColor'=> 'white',
                'borderRadius'=> 25,
                'borderWidth'=> 2,
                'color'=> 'white',
            ],
        ],
        'scales' => [
            'x' => ['display' => false,],
            'y' => ['display' => false,]
        ]
      ];
    }

    protected function getType(): string
    {
        return 'doughnut';
    }
}

